# Angular cli: getting it ready for production

Tags: angular, angular-cli, production

I wrote my first Angular 2 application, and I would like to put it onto a test server.

I recently converted it to an Angular-cli project and built it using the command :

```
ng build --prod
```

From what I understand, I should then be able to paste the contents of the "/dist" folder onto the test server and run it with

```
ng serve
```

However, If the "/dist" folder can run standalone, why am I unable to run it on my pc as a standalone app (ie, I cannot copy the contents of the dist folder to another place on the pc and run it.)

This will actually be the first application I will be putting onto a test/production server, so please bear with me if what I'm asking is silly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not, and I think cannot, use `ng serve` to publish your build. The files created with `ng build` can be uploaded to a webserver and served from there.

1. Run `ng build -e=prod --prod --no-sourcemap --aot`

Although the latest version of `angular-cli` defaults to no sourcemaps, it's worth noting here. The `-e=prod` will make sure it uses the production environment defined inside the `environments` folder. Last thing is the `--aot`. If you have no special things going on inside your project, there is a big chance you can have it pre-compiled using the ahead of time compiler. You can however run into problems and you can troubleshoot these using `ng serve --aot`, or remove the `--aot` altogether.

2. You can then continue to copy the contents of the `dist` folder to your webserver. It's worth noting though that you should make sure that all non existing file requests on the server will redirect to `index.html` and the url pointing to your application is in the root.

This means for `index.html` redirection on for instance `nginx`, you can put this inside your server configuration block:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

This is if www.example.com serves the `index.html` created inside the dist folder. If for some reason you would like to serve your application from a subfolder like, www.example.com/subfolder, then you should modify the `<base>` tag inside the generated `index.html` to point to this subfolder.

If you want to test your production build locally, one option is to install [`lite-server`](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server).

```
npm install -g lite-server
```

Then navigate in your console to `path/to/project/root/dist`, and run `lite-server`. This will create a webserver and open your browser, and serve the generated `index.html`

If you use `nginx` and want to be cool and serve the generated `.gz` files statically, you can place this inside your nginx gzip configuration:

```
gzip on;
gzip_static on;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Got it running on a lite-server (although the bootstrap doesn't load, so I have to do some config). Everyone else helped as well, but your lite-server suggestion was especially helpful. Marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`nb build --prod` put's all required files into `dist` folder.

You don't need `ng serve` to run built project.

You will need to put `dist` content into any server (even some kind of localhost)

`ng serve` is only for development with live reload.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: you can copy your app and run `ng serve --prod` (which is a bit excessive i think), or you can copy your `./dist` to an other server and use some server software (i.e. nginx, apache, express - there tons of it, you can choose the one you're familiar with). All you need is to pass all requests which not a file requests to an `index.html` as the angular app is SPA. Here's an example of `.htaccess` for an Apache server:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: While this .htaccess file basically works, if I use routes like /members it will redirect those to /index.html if I directly enter them into the browsers address line. Which is not what I want and not what ng serve does. Do you, maybe know a way to support the paths as well?