# Angular2 application hosting on shared linux server

Tags: angular, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

we have developed an Angular2 application with SQL Database.

1. In what kind of server I can host this application? for example: shared hosting or VPS?,
2. Do I have to install NodeJS and NPM on server?

please suggest your thoughts!

Comment: You can use server like nginx

Comment: You can upload your code on Google cloud or AWS S3 but use nginx its better

Comment: I have crated site in Angular 4 and Nodejs with mysql database its pretty fast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular cli: getting it ready for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890833/angular-cli-getting-it-ready-for-production)

Comment: @PierreDuc I dont think so Its a duplicate, my question is about hosting the production app and the one you referred one is talking about creating the production app.

Comment: @Sarav well, then stackoverflow is the wrong site to ask this :) this is for coding problems. Perhaps at https://serverfault.com/ you'll get more help.

Comment: @JalayOza thanks for your suggestion. let me check it out.

Comment: Welcome @Sarav please vote my comment also Thanks

Comment: @PierreDuc thank you. let me try to get help from there as well.